# Is it possible to iterate over mapReduce in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am using mapReduce in MongoDB to generate the trending songs for a user form his/her friends network. so I iterate over all users and check if the user_id exists in their friends array, if it exists I emit their songs and then merge the whole emitted songs to find the top songs for all his friends network.

The problem is that i need to iterate over all users to find the (network trending songs) for every user in the collection. How can I accomplish this, Is there way like nested mapReduce. or do I have to iterate from the application layer, like excuting mapReduce through a for loop!.

my current mapReduce that i am using is this one:

```
var map = function() {
users = [];
songs = [];
    if(this.value.friends !== undefined && this.value.friends.length !== 0 && this.value.songs !== undefined && this.value.songs.length !== 0){
        key = this._id.user_id;
        for(var x=0; x<this.value.songs.length; x++)
            emit({user_id:user_id,song_id:this.value.songs[x][0]},{played:this.value.songs[x][1], counter:1});
    }
};
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    var counter = 0;
    var played = 0;
    values.forEach(function(val){
        counter += val.counter;
        played += val.played;
    });
    return {played : played, counter : counter};
};
db.runCommand({"mapreduce":"trending_users", "map":map, "reduce":reduce, "scope":{user_id: "111222333444"} ,"query":{'value.friends':{$in : ['111222333444'] }},'out':{merge:'trending_user_network'}})    
db.trending_user_network.find({'_id.user_id':'111222333444'}).sort({'value.counter':-1, 'value.played':-1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly use a for-loop in your application to cycle over the user IDs and run your map reduce for each one. However, for something like this, you might have better luck using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) to create a pipeline of aggregate operations to do it all at once.

I don't know the precise details of your schema, but I think you could build an aggregation pipeline along the lines of this:

- `$unwind` to get a flat list of users mapped to their friends' user IDs
- `$unwind` again to map the friends' user IDs to their list of songs
- `$group` to get the aggregates of each song in the resulting list
- `$sort` to put the resulting stuff in order

In reality your pipeline might require a few more steps, but I think that if you look at this problem in terms of aggregation rather than map-reduce, it will be easier.

Comment: I am expecting to run the database over a shard environment, in this case the mapReduce will be more efficient. at the same time, if I had like 100k users, then iterating over them and calling mapReduce each time will be really a resource consuming task, and its a blocking job too. this is what confuses me. Thank you.

Comment: I believe the 2.2 aggregation framework supports sharded collections and it's much quicker than MR for on-demand queries, but the main issue is that it has to do everything in RAM. So for really big collections that's still a problem. Aggregation still isn't quick, but 2.2 as heads and shoulders over the old JS engine. With MR, you're using the JS engine, and it can't really be used on-demand. It's much better suited to stuff that you can pre-calculate and cache when it's less important how long it takes to build.

Comment: If you post some sample DB schema data and show some desired output we can have a go at building the aggregation query for you.

Comment: Here is the sample data, please note that this collection "tending_users" is the result of an intermediate mapReduce so i avoid having very large and complicated mapReduce functions. http://paste2.org/p/2288624 the desired output is every user_id with the all songs from his/her friends network. Thanks!